# Interpreting weights of Opencv SVM with linear kernel

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

When I train Linear SVM from Opencv on my data.

Actually it's a classification prolem on pixels(2 class).

I'm using simple features B,G,R,H,S,V and Max,Min,Mean,StdDev for each BGR channel so at all I have 18 features 6+4*3 and number of samples about k*100k).

But at the end of training, even when I testing on same data I get all predictions as class 1 and my SVM weights are weird, something like:

```
   support_vectors:
      - [ -2.77780177e+34, -4.16930769e+18, -2.63025906e+05, .Inf,
          -4.18178580e+24, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
          0., 0. ]
```

Comment: I'm puzzled about the paradigm: you have a different set of stats (channel max, min, mean SD) for *every* sample??  Can you post a few + and - observations so we can get a feel for the problem?  What concerns me most is that you have only one support vector, which means that you have no discrimination between classes (unless this is a 1-D space with the observation sets touching).  Also, that infinite hue is a distinct danger sign, and the HSV components don't match the BGR coefficients in front of them.

Comment: Also, a little code from the set-up and call would be helpful, especially if the problem is in the modelling parameters.  I'm not familiar with Opencv; I work with ML and LibSVM through the TrustedAnalytics API, but I'm hopeful that I'll recognize the tuning knobs when we get there.

Comment: @Prune OpenCV svm is just a wrapper on libsvm, shouldn't change much on what you are used to

Comment: Obviously, the data is not scaled, you cannot use SVM out of the box, read a little about how SVM works, get familiar with kernels and kernel params.